# How to use dynamic link in next js Image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

i want to use dynamic link in next js `Image` .
Next Js suggest

```
<Image
        src="/me.png"
        alt="Picture of the author"
        width={500}
        height={500}
      />
```

But i want to use like

```
const imageDynamic = [Image][1]
```

```
<Image
        src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image#/media/File:Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" or {imageDynamic}
        alt="Picture of the author"
        width={500}
        height={500}
      />
```

image will come from api so image src will change everytime. i can not use a link in next js Image , can it possbile to use a link in next js Image?

Comment: I'd suggest you have a read through [Image Component and Image Optimization docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#configuration).

Answer (score 5):

Next Image work similar like the html `img` tag. For the dynamic use case you should fetch dynamic data to the page.

to fetch the dynamic data you should use the `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` to pass the dynamic prop via url:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

```js
import Image from "next/image";

const WithDynamicImage = ({image}) => {

return (
    <Image src={image}
      alt="Picture of the author"
      width={500}
      height={500}
    />
)

}

export async function getServerSideProps({
  params,
}) {
  const image = await getImages() // fetch your data;
  const imageDynamic = image[param.id] //pass the prop from the url

  return { props: { image : imageDynamic || null } };
}

export default WithDynamicImage;
```

the data fetching only works in `pages/` folder and do not work in components. If you would use into component you should fetch the data in a page and pass the prop into the component.